# How to return custom http error codes with Spring MVC?

Tags: java, http, spring-mvc

My intention is to return custom http error codes with Spring MVC, for example: 601, 602 ... so that the customer can clearly differentiate between errors.

```
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public @ResponseBody
    ErrorAlmacen generalExceptionHandler(Exception exception, HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.setStatus(601);
        ErrorAlmacen error = new ErrorAlmacen();
        ...
        return error;
    }
```

But when my @ExceptionHandler set these values ​​in the respose object, Spring somehow translates to 200.

Is it possible to do what I am trying, or Spring is not going to allow me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is ***not*** possible to accomplish.

HTTP is a well-known protocol which can not re-design for your own usage.

A protocol is the "language", the rules that 2 parties aware of and now how to "speak" and communicate with each other.

When you deploy your web application to a web server, that web server can respond to HTTP requests from the client, the client would be a browser of an end user. and that browser expects to receive only and only 200 code for an OK response, and no other HTTP code for OK approval.

Your browser knows to resolve the status 200 and not the 602 that you wish to use.

That is how browsers are built, **and you can't change the protocol.**

Comment: My client is not a browser, it will be an application than will be able to understand that custom error codes.
So... ¿is not possible in Spring MVC to return custom codes?

Comment: Still, a protocol can't be changed to your needs. There are other ways to communicate with your client, Spring model, Ajax + json.